# Missing 'Stop Inheriting Permissions' Button

Tags: permissions, access, inheritance

I have a Sharepoint and there are sections where I'd like to restrict access to certain parts. I have done this on previous versions of sharepoint by removing the inheritance of permissions from the parent and then assigning each group to a folder.

I am trying to do this at the moment except I don't have the button to 'Stop Inheriting Permissions'. I understand it is usually between the 'Manage Parent' and 'Check Permissions' button on the top left of the screen on the manage permissions web page - sreenshot below

Could somebody help me to understand why the button isn't appearing?

[image]

Comment: maybe there is css in the masterpage to hide uniheritance. Does it show for any other objects in that site?

Comment: The template under which the site has been set up doesn't allow it as per the below summary in the site details scetion: "In the Controlled Security Template you can’t break permissions anywhere in the site, and you can’t add ‘everyone’ to the site. This is because access to sites with Highly Confidential Data has to be carefully controlled, approved and certified."

Do you know if it is possible to change the template under which a site is created?

Comment: So basically it's either a change in the masterpage, or a change in the css--all made into a template. If it's a site collection, you can open it up in SharePoint Designer and change the masterpage, or add a css stylesheet to the masterpage in the site settings-> masterpage, but you can't change templates after a site is created.

Answer (score 1):

You have independant permissions on that library.  It will only be available if the library is actually inheriting permissions.

Comment: So after we stop inherit permission from parent site, we can only modify who can access to the site instead of control the permission for a specific library or folder(s)?

Comment: the object is inheriting permissions, hence the Manage Parent option, there should be a stop inheriting permissions button there as well, which is his issue

Comment: he template under which the site has been set up doesn't allow it as per the below summary in the site details scetion: "In the Controlled Security Template you can’t break permissions anywhere in the site, and you can’t add ‘everyone’ to the site. This is because access to sites with Highly Confidential Data has to be carefully controlled, approved and certified." Do you know if it is possible to change the template under which a site is created?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend all our users "Inherit" permissions from the Master page and control the users in groups.

When you have a specific library with broken inheritance then you just add those "groups" to control the access to that Library.